# Can I programatically cancel user enabled fullscreen mode in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-fullscreen

I'm making a Chrome extension that depends on using popups. This is a problem if Chrome is in fullscreen mode as they do not appear.

I can disable programatically enabled fullscreen mode by using:

```
document.webkitCancelFullScreen()
```

However this does not work if the user has enabled fullscreen mode manually (F11 key). Is there a way to disable this or is it intentionally meant to only be manually disabled?

Comment: Why are you trying to control the will of the person that owns the computer? Perhaps they have problems with their sight

Comment: Regardless this being or not possible: don't interfere with user preferences.

Comment: I get that, was just curious to know if it's possible or not.